# SOURCEDIR path Setup Project Installation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project

I need to set dynamically InstallUrl of .NET 3.5 setup file.

For example, when I set a hardcore path like: file:///C:/temp/dotNetFx35Setup.exe it works, but my setup file is inside source folder where is the msi installation file.

I know that I can set property of prerequisite from same location and from vendor's site, but don't ask, this is my task.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you should use your MSI instead of Setup.exe because setup.exe will check for prerequisites before installing where MSI just installs with the assumption that you got all prerequisites.